# git merge untracked branch removes code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

I am working with a team on `git` and my local **untracked** `production branch` is missing lines of code from a team member.

My local `master` branch is `tracked` on the `remote/origin/master` and it shows all the code.

The local `production` branch was `checkedout` from `remote/origin/production` with this command

```
git checkout production
```

After finishing the `development branch` I did:

```
git checkout production
git merge development
```

I deploy to server and then

```
git checkout master
git merge development
git merge production
git push origin master
```

Later I find out that `production branch` and server are missing some lines of code (while `master` is ok)

I thought this could be caused by the fact that the remote branch was not `tracked` with `git checkout --track production`

Then I found that `git diff master..production` does not show differences, but analyzing the production branch I can find this `commit` relative to the merge of the `development` branch:

```
git show b17832a
commit b17832ae656f1bd43ebf837934f16b7d1f6efa33
Merge: a9bd850 0873d56
Merge branch 'development'
```

and here I can find the removed line of code

```
git diff a9bd850..0873d56 file.rb
diff --git a/file.rb
index e0d1d1b..2343d92 100644
--- a/file.rb
+++ b/file.rb
@@ -49,12 +49,6 @@ angular.module('sp').directive 'spPlayer', [
some text and below I can find
- my missing line of code
- is showing here
```

how can I fix the production branch and push the change? My commit on master have already been push to the remote.

Comment: If your `master` is ok, then what about if you pull `origin master` into `production` branch?

Comment: @SajibKhan I did not push production to the `remote/origin/production`, so I could just destroy it and `git checkout remote/origin/production`, but my master was already merged with the `branch production`. I don't know what to do. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: So, local `production` branch has problem. But `production` branch is merged with local `master` already by `git merge production` and now `master` is ok!?

Comment: yes, `master` was merged with `development` and `production` and it has the code, but `production` does not have it. Maybe I could recreate `production` based on `master`, but I don't know if that is okay for my team. `Production` was merged with `development`

Comment: if you merge `master` into `production` then the problem is solved I guess. Just backup your `production` & try it. `$ git checkout production; git branch production.bac; git merge master`. See if the problem is solved or not?

Comment: @SajibKhan you are right. In fact I totally misunderstood the `git diff` output, the remote is missing that commit and the problem is that I `checkout` a remote branch which did not have the latest code. That code is missing from the branch for that reason. The local version was later merged with master and for this reason it includes the code

Thanks a lot ... was really hard for me today and yesterday. If you want to post this as answer I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned:

> Later I find out that production branch and server are missing some lines of code (while master is ok)

Update local `production` with `master` then push to remote `production` (origin/production).

```
$ git checkout production
$ git merge master
$ git push origin production
```

---

Update `remote master` (origin/master)

```
$ git checkout master
$ git push origin master
```

**N.B.** the issue is solved discussing in OP's comment section actually.